# Adapter request does not return expected data

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

My worklight app has a page to post some values to a remote server. This is done using an adapter which calls  the url to post. The client javascript is:

```
var invocationData = {
    adapter : 'StoryAdaptor',
    procedure : 'postStoryDetails',
    parameters : [ storyParameters ]
};      

WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
    onSuccess : function(data) {
        alert("return message: "+JSON.stringify(data))
    },
    onFailure : function(data) {
        alert("Couldn't save Story");
    }
});
```

The adapter method is

```
function postStoryDetails(storyParameters){
  var input = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'json',   
        path : "/postStory.json",
        parameters : storyParameters
  };    
 var authResult = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

The remote application is a java Spring application which takes the parameters and on successful save, returns just a string "success".

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/postStory" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postStory(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
Story story = new Story();
story.setTitle(request.getParameter("title"));
.
.
.
boolean status = storyService.saveStory(story);
if(status ){
    return "success";    
}
 return "failed";
}
```

I am not getting the "success" message in worklght. Instead, each time, the alert is printing

```
return message: {"status":200,"invocationContext":null,"invocationResult":{"isSuccessful":true}}
```

Why I am not getting my returned message?

Comment: Maybe you are not returning it correctly. Edit the question with what & how you are returning it.

Comment: The string is supposed to be part of the JSON object that you are supposedly returning.

Comment: Have edited question - added the server function. The returned message is to be used in worklight for display.

Comment: Is returning "sussess" as just a string causing the problem? Do i need to return the message as a json string?

Answer (score 1):

Try returning like the following:

```
return {
    result: "success";
}
```

- For Worklight 6.2, see [Using Java in Adapters](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/04_12_Using_Java_in_adapters.pdf), slide #11
- For MobileFirst Platform 3.2, see [Using Java in Adapters](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/server-side-development/using-java-adapters/), section "Invoking custom Java classes from the adapter"